# Save variable labels in R so that Stata can read them

Tags: r, label, stata, data-management

I have a dataset with over `170` variables that looks as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = 1:3, var2 = 2:4, var3 = 2:4, var4 = 2:4, var5 = 2:4)
```

I have manually added variable values using `Hmisc`:

```
library(Hmisc)
var.labels = c(var1 = "label 1",
               var3 = "label 2",
               var4="label 4" )
label(df) = as.list(var.labels[match(names(df), names(var.labels))])
```

Do note that not all variables have labels and that it is much easier for me to specify variable labels by name (`var*`), rather than position given my large number of colums.

The problem is that when I save my dataset with `write.csv(df,"df.csv")`or with `write.dta(df,"df.dta")` my variable labels get lost.

How can I save the data in a way that can be re-imported into R and Stata with the labels restored?

Comment: Standard CSV files don't have any way to save labels. You can save an object in R in a binary format with `saveRDS` which would preserve labels but you can't read that into Stata. Perhaps you can just save the labels in a separate file and merge within each program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little tricky. You need to label all variables. If you do not want to label a variable, you may still need to put `variable = ""`.  Otherwise `write.dta` will ignore all variable labels.

In `R`

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = 1:3, var2 = 2:4, var3 = 2:4, var4 = 2:4, var5 = 2:4)
attr(df, "var.labels") <- c(var1 = "label 1", var2 = "label 2", 
              var3 = "", var4="label 4", var5 = "")
foreign::write.dta(df, "dat_stata.dta")
```

In `Stata`, you get:

```
. des

Contains data from C:...dat_stata.dta
  obs:             3                          Written by R.              
 vars:             5                          
 size:            60                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var1            long    %9.0g                 label 1
var2            long    %9.0g                 label 2
var3            long    %9.0g                 
var4            long    %9.0g                 label 4
var5            long    %9.0g                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by:
```

Please note: I used `Stata 14`, and `R` package `foreign`

Comment: I was wondering is there a way to automatically attribute empty labels to those variables to which I do not specifically assign a value? My dataset has over 700 variables and i only need to label those that are most relevant. something like `attr(df, "var.labels") <- c(var1 = "label 1", var2 = "label 2" 
              , var4="label 4")` and then tell r to automatically assign `""` to the rest of the variables

Comment: It works, but you have to make sure to ADD A LABEL TO EACH VARIABLE, otherwise, it will not work!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the colnames of the dataframe to those labels that are available:

```
colnames(df)[which(!is.na(label(df)))]<-as.character(label(df)[which(!is.na(label(df)))])
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but this is not really what I want, I would like to have my variable names that are easily accessible and then have labels saved so that when I have doubts on the data I know what it is about.